# Is it possible to tell BugzScout to stop reporting on a specific exception or set FogBugz to stop tracking that exception?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand, bugzscout

We have an exception that pops up on our website that is getting reported to BugzScout many times a day.  The functionality that produces the exception still does what it's intended to do, so we just want to stop FogBugz from piling up all of these occurrences until we have a chance to dig into the issue and prevent the exception.

That said, is there a way to set up a filter on the FogBugz side of things to ignore a list of exceptions that get reported? I know I can set up some logic in our app's BugzScout class so it stops sending those messages, but it would be nice to know if FogBugz does this already before I put the time into building that filter locally.  We are using the hosted FogBugz On Demand version of the product if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the BugzScout case itself, you should be able to set "Stop Reporting" for the *Scout Will* setting. This way, only the occurrences will increment when the exception is reported. The case will not reopen or notify anyone.

It sounds a bit from your description that there are many different exceptions reporting to the same ScoutDescription. As much as possible, you should use version numbers and exception line numbers to make sure that exceptions are reported separately. I can elaborate on this if you want.